# why pslsp is not returning correct definition?

Tags: python, types, language-server-protocol, python-language-server, pylsp

I am asking for a go to definition request to pylsp using websockets. However, correct deifinition is not returned.

Here is the definition_request:

```
definition_request = {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 2,
    "method": "textDocument/definition",
    "params": {
        "textDocument": {
            "uri": "file://" + os.path.join(root_path, file_name)
        },
        "position": {
            "line": line,
            "character": character
        }
    }
}
```

For the following code, I want to get the defition for `check_files_in_directory` which is definied in the `GPT4Readability.utils` file. But somehow pylsp is not able to provide me with the correct definition location.

GPT4Readability/readme_gen.py file:

```
import os
from getpass import getpass
from GPT4Readability.utils import *
import importlib.resources as pkg_resources  


def generate_readme(root_dir, output_name, model):
    """Generates a README.md file based on the python files in the provided directory

    Args:
        root_dir (str): The root directory of the python package to parse and generate a readme for
    """

    # prompt_folder_name = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "prompts")
    # prompt_path = os.path.join(prompt_folder_name, "readme_prompt.txt")

    with pkg_resources.open_text('GPT4Readability.prompts','readme_prompt.txt') as f:         
        inb_msg = f.read()

    # with open(prompt_path) as f:
    #     lines = f.readlines()
    # inb_msg = "".join(lines)

    file_check_result = check_files_in_directory(root_dir)
....
```

I get the following response:

```
finish pylsp_definitions --> [[{'uri': 'file:///path/to/the/repo/GPT4Readability/GPT4Readability/readme_gen.py', 'range': {'start': {'line': 25, 'character': 4}, 'end': {'line': 25, 'character': 29}}}]]
```

Very strange as it thinks that check_files_in_directory is defined in the same `GPT4Readability/readme_gen.py` file. Why is that?

Am I missing something in this case?